# Spring Boot JPA @Query and mapping problem" Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have problem with my web application. I need to display in **List**things from 4 tables.
My main table is "umowienia" "**appointment**" and it have connection one to many with klienci AS **"clients"**, pracownik AS **"employee"**, usługi AS **"services"**, and stanowiska AS **"positions"**

I want to connect this tables to display it on List on one of the application pages.

**When I connect tables program say to me error like this**

```
Error creating bean with name 'realizacjeRepository' defined in figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.repository.RealizacjeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: klienci, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(umowienia)]
```

My application look like this:
[construction of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW7Ph.png)

Data base is on secodn screen [screen of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACt6s.png)

And my files:

Umowienia.java

```
package figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.model;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "umowienia")
public class Umowienia {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_umowienia")
    private Integer id_umowienia;

    @Column
    private Date data_umowienia;

    @Column
    private Time czas_trwania;

    @Column
    private String komentarz;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_klienta", referencedColumnName = "id_klienta", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Klienci klienci;




    public Klienci getKlienci() {
        return klienci;
    }

    public void setKlienci(Klienci klienci) {
        this.klienci = klienci;
    }

    public Integer getId_umowienia() {
        return id_umowienia;
    }

    public void setId_umowienia(Integer id_umowienia) {
        this.id_umowienia = id_umowienia;
    }

    public Date getData_umowienia() {
        return data_umowienia;
    }

    public void setData_umowienia(Date data_umowienia) {
        this.data_umowienia = data_umowienia;
    }

    public Time getCzas_trwania() {
        return czas_trwania;
    }

    public void setCzas_trwania(Time czas_trwania) {
        this.czas_trwania = czas_trwania;
    }

    public String getKomentarz() {
        return komentarz;
    }

    public void setKomentarz(String komentarz) {
        this.komentarz = komentarz;
    }
}
```

Klienci.java

```
package figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.model;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "klienci")
public class Klienci {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_klienta")
    private Integer id_klienta;

    @Column(name = "imie")
    private String imieKlienta;

    @Column(name = "nazwisko")
    private String nazwiskoKlienta;

    @Column(name = "nr_telefonu_klienta")
    private Integer nrTelefonuKlienta;

    @Column(name = "adres_email")
    private  String adresEmailKlienta;

    private List<Umowienia> umowienia;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Umowienia.class, mappedBy = "klienci",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Umowienia> getUmowienia() {
        return umowienia;
    }








    public void setUmowienia(List<Umowienia> umowienia) {
        this.umowienia = umowienia;
    }

    public Klienci(){
    }

    public Integer getId_klienta() {
        return id_klienta;
    }

    public void setId_klienta(Integer id_klienta) {
        this.id_klienta = id_klienta;
    }

    public String getImieKlienta() {
        return imieKlienta;
    }

    public void setImieKlienta(String imieKlienta) {
        this.imieKlienta = imieKlienta;
    }

    public String getNazwiskoKlienta() {
        return nazwiskoKlienta;
    }

    public void setNazwiskoKlienta(String nazwiskoKlienta) {
        this.nazwiskoKlienta = nazwiskoKlienta;
    }

    public Integer getNrTelefonuKlienta() {
        return nrTelefonuKlienta;
    }

    public void setNrTelefonuKlienta(Integer nrTelefonuKlienta) {
        this.nrTelefonuKlienta = nrTelefonuKlienta;
    }

    public String getAdresEmailKlienta() {
        return adresEmailKlienta;
    }

    public void setAdresEmailKlienta(String adresEmailKlienta) {
        this.adresEmailKlienta = adresEmailKlienta;
    }
}
```

Pracownicy.java

```
package figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.model;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pracownik")
public class Pracownicy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_pracownika")
    private Integer id_pracownika;

    @Column(name = "imie")
    private String imiePracownika;

    @Column(name = "nazwisko")
    private String nazwiskoPracownika;

    @Column(name = "nr_tele_pracownika")
    private Integer nrTelefonuPracownika;

    @Column(name = "typ_pracownika")
    private String typPracownika;


+getters and setters
```

Stanowiska.java

```
package figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.model;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "stanowiska")
public class Stanowiska {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_stanowiska")
    private Integer id_stanowiska;

    @Column(name = "numer_stanowiska")
    private Integer numerStanowiska;
+getters and setters
```

Uslugi.java

```
package figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.model;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "uslugi")
public class Uslugi {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_uslugi")
    private Integer id_uslugi;

    @Column(name = "nazwa_uslugi")
    private String nazwaUslugi;

    @Column(name = "cena_uslugi")
    private Integer cenaUslugi;
```

**FILE TO DISPLAY LIST**
UmowieniaRepository

```
package figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.repository;


import figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.model.Umowienia;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;




@Repository
public interface UmowieniaRepository  extends JpaRepository<Umowienia, Integer> {
}
```

UmowieniaService

```
package figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.service.umowienia;

import figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.model.Umowienia;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
@Service
public interface UmowieniaService {


    List<Umowienia> getAllUmowienia();
    void saveUmowienia(Umowienia umowienia);
}
```

UmowieniaServiceImpl

```
package figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.service.umowienia;


import figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.model.Umowienia;
import figura.zaklad_fryzjerski_v3.repository.UmowieniaRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UmowieniaServiceImpl implements UmowieniaService {

    @Autowired
    private UmowieniaRepository umowieniaRepository;

  
    @Override
    public List<Umowienia> getAllUmowienia() {
        return umowieniaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUmowienia(Umowienia umowienia) {
        this.umowieniaRepository.save(umowienia);
    }


}
```

**If you need more code just write and I'll add it**

Comment: Have you tried putting the annotations above the field instead of the getter method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using field access strategy (determined by @Id annotation). Put any JPA related annotation right above each field instead of getter property like this in your kilenci entity

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Umowienia.class, mappedBy = "klienci",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

public List<Umowienia> umowienias;
```

Comment: I make what you write

`
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Umowienia.class, mappedBy = "klienci",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Umowienia> umowienias;


    public List<Umowienia> getUmowienias() {
        return umowienias;
    }

    public void setUmowienias(List<Umowienia> umowienias) {
        this.umowienias = umowienias;
    }
`

And error disapear

Comment: yes it works, try tommorow add rest of tables. I write if it gona work. When i waiting i make it by using Query :D

Comment: Thanks man, if anything else comes up reply in this comment, i will try to help you :D